# how to update listview in onProgressUpdate()

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask

I am new in android i want to fetch contacts and display in list view .Here is the code i to fetch contacts in asynctask.please help how to update list view after fetching each contact.

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
         ContentResolver cr = ReadContactsActivity.this.getContentResolver();
         Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);

         if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
             while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                 String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                 String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                 if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                     Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                                            new String[]{id}, null);
                     while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                           String phone = pCur.getString(
                                  pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        //li.add("Name:"+name+",Number:"+phone);
                           publishProgress("Name:"+name+",Number:"+phone);
                     }
                     pCur.close();
                     }
                 }
             }
        return null;
    }


    // A callback method executed on UI thread, invoked by the publishProgress() 
    // from doInBackground() method
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
         list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvDisplay);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adp=new ArrayAdapter<String> 
        (getBaseContext(),R.layout.list,R.id.label,li);
        list.setAdapter(adp);       
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How you are using your listviews and adapters is quite off.

- Do not use findViewById everytime, store a reference to it instead
- Do not set up a new adapter everytime, instead change the underlying data and call
- Always do your one time set ups (getting a reference to listview, initializing adapter etc..) in `OnPreExecute`

  ```
  ListView list;
  List<String> names;
  ArrayAdapter<string> adapter;

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
      names = new ArrayList<String>();
      list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvDisplay);
      ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>     
          (getBaseContext(),
           R.layout.list,
           R.id.label,
           names);
      list.setAdapter(adp);  
  }

  // doInBackground() ...

  @Override
  protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
       names.add(values[0])
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
  ```

Note: In this case I would actually recommend that you keep the references for the Adapter, listView and the underlying data *outside* the AsyncTask. You can still use these references, and you also have the ability to use them in your outer class when needed (which is very likely)

Comment: this code don't tell the Adapter that it should use the names List. i suggest using `adapter.add(values[0]); adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` in onProgressUpdate

Comment: actually, since the adapter is using the `ArrayList<String> names`, we can just add the name to the arraylist and ask the adapter to update.

Comment: ok, but you still would need to add `names = new ArrayList<String>();` :)

Comment: `findViewById` Where's context to find view from it by id ?

Answer (score 1):

Put it in onPostExecute() like this

```
@Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String... values) {
      super.onPostExecute(result);
      list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvDisplay);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adp=new ArrayAdapter<String> 
    (getBaseContext(),R.layout.list,R.id.label,li);
    list.setAdapter(adp); 
   }
```

Comment: This will execute when all the records are fetched but i need to update list view on each fetch

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE: Ahmed fixed his answer... https://stackoverflow.com/a/15381932/1659588**

<strike>Based on the answer of Ahmed Aeon Axan here is a fixed version</strike>

```
ListView list;
ArrayAdapter<string> adapter;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvDisplay);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>     
        (getBaseContext(),R.layout.list,R.id.label,li);
        list.setAdapter(adp);  
}

// doInBackground() ...

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
     adapter.add(values[0]);
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: This gives error "The method add(R.string) in the type ArrayAdapter<R.string> is not applicable for the arguments (String)" please help how to fix

Comment: Use the updated answer by Ahmed Aeon Axan http://stackoverflow.com/a/15381932/1659588